# Whats is the meaning of "rel" in the optional elements such as collectionResourceRel in RepositoryRestResource annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

Can you please help me understand the meaning of "rel" mentioned optional element of RepositoryRestResource annotation's collectionResourceRel?
I have gone through Java Docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/annotation/RepositoryRestResource.html).

Below is what is written in the documentation.

> collectionResourceRel The rel value to use when generating links to
>   the collection resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicly `rel` is an attribute of `@RestResource` annotation. It means "relationship"

e.g. an order might have a `"rel" : "customer"` relationship that links the order to its customer.

From https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/ :

For instance, in the default configuration, if you issue a request to `http://localhost:8080/persons/search` to find out what query methods are exposed, you get back a list of links similar to the following:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "findByName" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/persons/search/findByName"
    }
  }
}
```

To change the `rel` value, use the `rel` property on the `@RestResource` annotation, as the following example shows:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "people")
interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {

  @RestResource(path = "names", rel = "names")
  List<Person> findByName(String name);
}
```

The preceding example results in the following link value:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "names" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/persons/search/names"
    }
  }
}
```

You can change the rel of a repository, as the following example shows:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "people", rel = "people")
interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {

  @RestResource(path = "names", rel = "names")
  List<Person> findByName(String name);
}
```

Altering the rel of a repository changes the top-level name, as the following example output shows:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "people" : {  // rel = "people"
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/people"
    },
    …
  }
}
```

`rel = "people"` changed the name of that link to `people`.

Q: Do you have an example showing "an order might have a "rel" : "customer" relationship that links the order to its customer."? Does it also consider relationship between the entities such as OneToMany, ManyToMany etc.

It is different from the relationship between the entities such as OneToMany, ManyToMany.

The relation describes how the current resource is **related to the target resource.**

Here is a good example from https://restfulapi.net/hateoas/ to understand  `rel` :

Below given JSON response may be from an API like `HTTP GET` http://api.domain.com/management/departments/10

```
{
    "departmentId": 10,
    "departmentName": "Administration",
    "locationId": 1700,
    "managerId": 200,
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "10/employees",
            "rel": "employees",
            "type" : "GET"
        }
    ]
}
```

In the preceding example, the response returned by the server contains hypermedia links to employee resources 10/employees, which can be traversed by the client to read employees belonging to the department.

It is between presentation and data layer. The link created with the help of rel and other attributes:

```
{
    "href": "10/employees",
    "rel": "employees",
    "type" : "GET"
}
```

helps the application to go to the right direction (repository, method etc. ) to retrieve the data (employees belonging to the department)

According to your design you can also create relations between entities in the data layer. But these are different things.

Comment: Do you have an example showing "an order might have a "rel" : "customer" relationship that links the order to its customer."? Does it also consider relationship between the entities such as OneToMany, ManyToMany etc. And if that is the case how would it behave?

Answer (score 1):

In a `HATEOAS` API, `rel` "describes how the current context (source) is related to the target resource"

https://restfulapi.net/hateoas/